# Error cannot find symbol !numero.equals(rand)

Tags: java

Parece que el `do while` me da error en la variable `numero`...

> error: cannot find symbol while ( !numero.equals(rand) );

```
System.out.println("Jugar Partida");
      //Crear número con random
      Random r = new Random();
      int rand=r.nextInt(10)+1;
      System.out.println(rand);

      //Tomar datos de usuario
      do{
      Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Introduce numero: ");
      int numero = teclado.nextInt();
      System.out.println(numero);
      } while ( !numero.equals(rand) );
```

Comment: Declara la variable `numero` antes del while y adentro solo ponle `numero = teclado.nextInt();`

Comment: ok, ¿y si fuera un variable tipo string ocurre lo mismo y se trata igual?

Comment: Así es, con cualquier tipo de variable u objeto, si las tienes que usar dentro de alguna condicional, bucle o método y aparte las vas a usar fuera de estos entonces tienes que asegurarte que sean declaradas antes osea al nivel de tu método principal, en caso de que sean variables que solo las necesites usar adentro de algún bucle entonces no importaría declararlas dentro.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te dejo una mejor forma de hacerlo, mayormente el equals se utiliza cuando se trabaja con strings.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Prueba {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Jugar Partida");
          //Crear número con random
          Random r = new Random();
          int numero=0;
          int rand=r.nextInt(10)+1;
          System.out.println(rand);

          //Tomar datos de usuario
          do{
          Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.print("Introduce numero: ");
          numero = teclado.nextInt();
          System.out.println(numero);
          } while ( numero!=rand );
        }
}
```

Comment: podrías añadir a tu respuesta una explicación de lo que cambiaste del código y por qué?

Comment: Para poder utilizar una variable en todos los ámbitos es necesario declararla de forma global.

Comment: ¿Cómo declarar de forma global en el main de la misma manera?

Comment: Si solo vas a utilizarla en el Main, declarala debajo del método antes de hacer las operaciones.